# How to get value of selected checkbox using php?

Tags: javascript, php

I need help with collecting all the selected checkbox options from *Special Orders* and display it as text strings inside the modal. The checked options should be separated by commas.

I'm clearly new to JS, I have tried to look for solutions but I can't seem comprehend them at all and have been stucked in this part for ages.

the code is here...

```html
<form action="save_schedule.php" method="post" id="schedule-form">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title" id="title" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="recipient" class="control-label">Name of the Recipient</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="recipient" name="recipient" id="recipient" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="phone" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" placeholder="Phone number" name="phone" id="phone" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-6">
    <label for="orders" class="control-label">Special Orders</label>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">Pancit
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Spaghetti
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Carbonara
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Palabok 
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Baked Mac
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Maja
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          Banana Sliced
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          Fish Fillet
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Chicken Curry
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Kaldereta
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Menudo 
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Chopsuey
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
          <label class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
            Grilled Liempo
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check">
           <label class="form-check-label">
             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
             Beef Teriyaki
           </label>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>   
                                                                                 
     <div class="form-group mb-2">
       <label for="description" class="control-label">Notes</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="description" placeholder="Type the description" id="description" required></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mb-2">
       <label for="address" class="control-label">Delivery Address</label>                                          
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="House #, Street, City" aria-label="Username" name="address" id="address" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mb-2">
       <label for="start_datetime" class="control-label">Delivery Date</label>
       <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="start_datetime" id="start_datetime" required>
     </div>
</form>

<!-- Event Details Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-bs-backdrop="static" id="event-details-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content rounded-0">
      <div class="modal-header rounded-0">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Order Details</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body rounded-0">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <dl>
            <dt class="text-muted">Title</dt>
            <dd id="title" class="fw-bold fs-4"></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Name of the Recipient</dt>
            <dd id="recipient" class=""></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Phone Number</dt>
            <dd id="phone" class=""></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Special Orders</dt>
            <dd id="" class=""></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Notes</dt>
            <dd id="description" class=""></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Delivery Address</dt>
            <dd id="address" class=""></dd>
            <dt class="text-muted">Delivery Date</dt>
            <dd id="start" class=""></dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer rounded-0">
        <div class="text-end">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" id="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Event Details Modal -->
```

save_schedule.php

```php
require_once('../config/connection.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !='POST') {
    echo "<script> alert('Error: No data to save.'); location.replace('./') </script>";
    $con->close();
    exit;
}
extract($_POST);
$allday = isset($allday);

if(empty($id)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `calendar` (`title`,`recipient`,`phone`,`description`,`address`,`start_datetime`) VALUES ('$title','$recipient','$phone','$description','$address','$start_datetime')";
}else{
    $sql = "UPDATE `calendar` set `title` = '{$title}', `recipient` = '{$recipient}', `phone` = '{$phone}',`description` = '{$description}',`address` = '{$address}',`start_datetime` = '{$start_datetime}' where `id` = '{$id}'";
}
$save = $con->query($sql);
if($save){
    echo "<script> alert('Schedule Successfully Saved.'); location.replace('./special-orders.php') </script>";
}else{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "An Error occured.<br>";
    echo "Error: ".$con->error."<br>";
    echo "SQL: ".$sql."<br>";
    echo "</pre>";
}
$con->close();
```

script.js

```js
    var calendar;
    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var events = [];
    $(function() {
        if (!!scheds) {
            Object.keys(scheds).map(k => {
                var row = scheds[k]
                events.push({ id: row.id, title: row.title, start: row.start_datetime });
            })
        }
        var date = new Date()
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear()

        calendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,list',
                center: 'title',
            },
            selectable: true,
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            //Random default events
            events: events,
            eventClick: function(info) {
                var _details = $('#event-details-modal')
                var id = info.event.id
                if (!!scheds[id]) {
                    _details.find('#title').text(scheds[id].title)
                    _details.find('#recipient').text(scheds[id].recipient)
                    _details.find('#phone').text(scheds[id].phone)
                    _details.find('#description').text(scheds[id].description)
                    _details.find('#address').text(scheds[id].address)
                    _details.find('#start').text(scheds[id].sdate)
                    
                    _details.find('#edit,#delete').attr('data-id', id)
                    _details.modal('show')
                } else {
                    alert("Event is undefined");
                }
            },
            eventDidMount: function(info) {
                // Do Something after events mounted
            },
            editable: true
        });

        calendar.render();

        // Form reset listener
        $('#schedule-form').on('reset', function() {
            $(this).find('input:hidden').val('')
            $(this).find('input:visible').first().focus()
        })

        // Edit Button
        $('#edit').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            if (!!scheds[id]) {
                var _form = $('#schedule-form')
                console.log(String(scheds[id].start_datetime), String(scheds[id].start_datetime).replace(" ", "\\t"))
                _form.find('[name="id"]').val(id)
                _form.find('[name="title"]').val(scheds[id].title)
                _form.find('[name="recipient"]').val(scheds[id].recipient)
                _form.find('[name="phone"]').val(scheds[id].phone)
                _form.find('[name="description"]').val(scheds[id].description)
                _form.find('[name="address"]').val(scheds[id].address)
                _form.find('[name="start_datetime"]').val(String(scheds[id].start_datetime).replace(" ", "T"))
                
                $('#event-details-modal').modal('hide')
                _form.find('[name="title"]').focus()
            } else {
                alert("Event is undefined");
            }
        })

        // Delete Button / Deleting an Event
        $('#delete').click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            if (!!scheds[id]) {
                var _conf = confirm("Are you sure to delete this scheduled event?");
                if (_conf === true) {
                    location.href = "./delete_schedule.php?id=" + id;
                }
            } else {
                alert("Event is undefined");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Add some code which you have tried

Comment: Format your HTML so it doesn't go off the screen.   Or is normal for you to put 44 spaces in front of each line of code for no reason? Yeah, I counted them.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything the form submits can be found in global `$_REQUEST` variable.

First debug/check what your form-submit produces, like:

```
var_dump( $_REQUEST );
```

But (as mentioned in comments) your checkbox-inputs do not have any names, hence they never get submitted, to fix that set the name attribute in HTML like:

```
<input type="checkbox"
       name="myCoolCheckbox"
       id="my-checkbox-id"
       checked="checked">
<label for="my-checkbox-id">My Checkbox title</label>
```

However, you want to simply show a list of checked check-boxes, for that try something like:

```
var labels = '';

var _form = $('#schedule-form');
_form.find('[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
    if (labels !== '') {
        labels += ', ';
    }
    labels += $(this).text();
});

// Fill placeholder:
var _details = $('#event-details-modal');
_details.find('#checked-options').text(labels);
```

Also, add to modal the placeholder's HTML:

```html
<dt class="text-muted">Checked options</dt>
<dd id="checked-options" class=""></dd>
```

Comment: RE: "Once you know the names".   Did you mean once you add names to the checkboxes?  The checkboxes have no names.

Comment: Your `var_dump( $_REQUEST );)` is definitely a good idea.  I think there is an attempt to set the checkbox name in JavaScript.  Your` var_dump()` would confirm whether the JavaScript gave the checkboxes a `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox inputs do not have a name.
`<input/>` needs a name.

If you use JavaScript to add the names, that is insane. Did you develop this code on your own, or did you copy and paste?   If this copy and paste I could help you develop code that will work very well.  There is no need to use JavaScript.

```
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                              <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                                              Pancit
                                              </label>
                                            </div>
```

See the `name="Pancit"`

```
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="Pancit" class="form-check-input">
                                              Pancit
                                              </label>
                                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  // Get the output text
  var text = document.getElementById("text");

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I found from the below link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp

Comment: The checkboxes have neither an `id` nor a `name`.  That and this is not a JavaScript issue.